# How to perform server side DB polling in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, mongodb, signalr

I have an application running on angular.js, WebAPI, and mongodb. My goal is to replace client side polling, with signalr. Since mongodb doesn't fire events on changes, I still need to poll on the server side, and if I detect a change, broadcast it using a signalr hub.

**Is there a solid way to do that, without breaking the recurring task by IIS?**

What have I tried:

1. Hangfire: Seems like the recommended solution, but currently supports only SQL Server and redis (not an option).
2. HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem: Might work, but I fear that it is not widely used, and I might miss some pitfalls.
3. There's a way to kind of get events from mongo using "tailable cursor on capped collection" - not an option

Comment: My standard response to this kind of questions, cant you signal a event when you change state in DB?

Comment: @Anders - No. Another (non web) component is changing the DB. There can't be a direct connection between that component and the API.

Comment: cant you use a service bus? That way the "component" only publish messages and the web server subscribes to them.

Comment: No. There are other concerns that limit the web application to communicate only with the DB. If we could, we would, and I wouldn't bother asking this question...

Comment: Its bad practice to let several systems access the same DB, but it is what it is

Answer (score 2):

The answer as always: "it depends".

- HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem. The latest addition in .NET 4.5.2. No guarantees on execution, see the limitations at the end of [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx):
- [WebBackgrounder](https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder). Quote from Scott Hanselman [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx): "Its code hasn't been touched in years, BUT the WebBackgrounder NuGet package has been downloaded almost a half-million times".
- Hangfire. Popular open source project, adding mongodb support is always a welcome PR :)
- Using RavenDb instead of MongoDb. Their [Changes API](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/changes-api) is really cool.

The first and second options don't guarantee job execution, the third and fourth options rely on data stores instead.

Answer (score 0):

QueueBackgroundWorkItem is your best option consider what we discussed above, but its not 100% bullet proof. The app pool will still recycle. You can create a Windows service that signal the Web app to poll the DB.

Anyway, once you got the singal (through polling or what not) you could use event driven design from that point on. The benefit is decoupled domains and scalability.. I have created this framework for just that.

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Comment: As I said, creating another service is not an option. Your library seems nice but has nothing to do with my question. Do you have anything to comment on QBWI, besides not being 100% bullet proof? The app pool will always recycle - the point is how to deal with that properly.

Comment: You havent said that, but OK. Anyway, using the CancellationToken you can safly complete your task before the app recycles.

Comment: Here is a good blog that covers the different ways to do background work in ASP.NET
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html